# Compression of a text that contains only the 5 first letters of the alphabet?

Tags: data-compression, huffman-coding

So the question is: "Imagine the compression of a text written only with the first 5 characters of the alphabet (a, b, c, d, e). Knowing that their apparition's frequency is 1)e, 2)a, 3)c, 4)d, 5)b, code the letters on the minimum bits possible."

so here's how I did start:

We have 5 characters, so 3bits will be enough for the characters (2^3 =8). We can put: e=001, a=010, c=100, d=011, b=110 But I don't see how to use their frequency (we don't have the value of it, they just gave a "scale" of their frequency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you get an idea: You could encode f letters by assigning 00 = a, 01 = b, 10 = c, 110 = d, 111 = e. If their frequencies are a ≥ b ≥ c ≥ d ≥ e, then this will be the optimal fixed-width encoding unless a is very common. If a was very common then you would assign 0 = a and find a good way to encode b, c, d and e. Anyway, this would save one bit every time a letter a, b or c is used.

If you decided to encode 0 = a, 100 = b, 101 = c, 110 = d, 111 = e, that would save one bit compared to the first encoding every time you encode an a, and lose one bit every time you encode b or c. So this is a better encoding if the freq (a) > freq (b) + freq (c). One more possibility is 0 = a, 10 = b, 110 = c, 1110 = d, 1111 = e; you'd have to calculate the average number of bits for this case as well.

(And google for Huffman to find this method fully worked out).

Yes, Huffman coding would take the two codes with the lowest frequences and combine them into one. For example, d and e are combined into one code de, and you follow for "de" by 0 to get a d, and you follow the code for "de" by 1 to get an e. And then you pick again the two codes with the lowest frequencies. Which would be either b and c, or c and "de". And so on.

Comment: Can you specify *exactly* when which case happens? (Contrary to my earlier comments, the exact frequencies *do matter*.)

Comment: @gnasher729 that makes sense to me, thanks !!!

Correct me if I'm wrong:
So for Huffman method, we start with e+d on the bottom then we have two possibilities: either fr(c) superior or inferior to fr(d)+fr(e). Then two other possibilities for b ... 

PS: I know the exercice is not that clear, but it was written like that by the prof (it comes from an exam of 2 weeks ago)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the algorithm for creating Huffman trees/codes, you will see that while it uses frequencies, any weight works. You can always rescale (by dividing by the sum of all weights), if you wish.

If your problem does not contain any weights but only a relative order, you can not build a Huffman tree; you don't know where in the order the inner nodes you create go. Ask your teacher.

Comment: I went to his office but he's on vacation according to his secretary and won't be available until the day of our exam (that takes place 4 days from now). So I am helpless for now

Comment: @ChromeObie We won't be able to read your teacher's mind, sorry.

Comment: You can of course build a tree - you just don't know if it is optimal. And you can definitely improve on 5 codes of 3 bits each.